# How to call a function of a related (but different) C++ concept?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I have a concept `concept_a` and a second concept `concept_ab` with more requirements, e.g.

```
    template<typename T> concept concept_a = ...;

    template<typename T> concept concept_b = ...;

    template<typename T> concept concept_ab = concept_a<T> && concept_b<T>;
```

Now I have some function `f` for these concepts. In the function for the more strict concept I want to reuse the function for the less strict concept:

```
    int f(concept_a auto a) {return 1;}
    int f(concept_ab auto ab)
    {
       int n =f<concept_a> (ab);
       return n+10;
    }
```

This, however, does not work since `f<concept_a>` is syntactically not valid. Of course, I can solve this problem by adding another level of indirection, (i.e. add a function `f_concept_a` that is called by both `f`). My question is: is there is a direct way to call a function of a different (but related) concept?

Comment: Yes, it is a similar question with the same short anwer (there is no direct way) but an other long answer (possible alternative solution)

Answer (score 0):

The result of a template is based on the template arguments used to instantiate it. Constraints aren't template arguments, only types, values (of a very limited sort), and other templates can be template arguments. `f<something>` for a given `something` will always refer to the same template instantiation. You're using template argument deduction and function overloading, but the overall effect is the same: you can't have `f(ab)` call anything other than that instantiation of the template.

The correct way to handle this is to have some `f_name` function which does what your first `f` function does. You can rewrite your first `f` function to just call that one.

Comment: Yes, I know that the problem can be solved using ```f_concept_a``` (or ```f_name``` as you named it). Depending on the situation there might be other solutions, e.g. ```f(static_cast<A>(ab))``` will work if ```ab``` can be casted to some *pure* ```concept_A```. The question is simply whether there is already a built-in solution in the C++ language or whether I have to write a solution myself.